# How do I make Express JS run code when when subadress is ajax queried

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express

Sorry for the title. Don't really know how to put it. Anyways, I have an Express.js server running and I want to run the code below when I enter `192.168.1.88/run`.

The code that runs the python script:

```
exec('python3 /var/www/html/dbfetch.py', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    res.write('Command has failed'); //write a response to the client
    res.end(); //end the response
    return;
}
console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);

res.write('Command has been run'); //write a response to the client
res.end(); //end the response
});
```

Express server code:

```
    const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const port = 80
const path = require('path');
const helmet = require('helmet');

app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.static("/var/www/html"));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('hello.html', {root: __dirname});
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Loss Counter is listening on port ${port}!`))
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Express server is on `192.168.1.88`, then just create a route for the URL `http://192.168.1.88/run` in your Express server:

```
app.get("/run", (req, res) => {
    exec('python3 /var/www/html/dbfetch.py', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            res.status(500).send('Command has failed'); // write a response to the client
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);

        res.send('Command has been run'); // write a response to the client
    });
});
```